# Action property dropdown displays 'You cannot set property...'

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I've recently ported an application from *Delphi 2007* to *Delphi XE7*.
For doing this, I have created a new package project in *Delphi XE7* and copied the list of forms from the `contains` section of the old *Delphi 2007* `dpk` project file.

In a VCL Form (`TForm` descendant), the *Object Inspector* displays `'You cannot set property...'` for all `TAction` properties instead of displaying the list of the `TAction` objects.

[image: Object inspector displaying 'you cannot set property...' message for a TAction property]

Clicking on the message, a dialog saying `'Actions not implemented for the current framework 'None'` appears:

[image: Dialog displaying 'Actions not implemented for the current framework 'None'' message]

I thought it could be some problem related to the datamodule's [`ClassGroup`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/ClassGroup_pseudo-property_of_TDataModule) property but all the datamodules used by the form have `ClassGroup = Vcl.Controls.TControl` set.

The project is compiled using the following *Unit scope names* (Options -> Delphi Compiler):
`Winapi;System.Win;Data.Win;Datasnap.Win;Web.Win;Soap.Win;Xml.Win;Bde;System;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;Soap;Vcl;Vcl.Imaging;Vcl.Touch;Vcl.Samples;Vcl.Shell`

Comment: How can we reproduce this issue?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You could reproduce the error by setting 'None' as current framework for a project, but I was not able to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've reproduced the problem by following these steps:

- File -> New -> Package - Delphi
- Right click on "Package1.bpl"
  from the Project Manager -> Add New -> VCL Form
- A dialog asking to enable the "Visual Component Library" framework for the project will prompt up, choose "No" [image: Dialog asking for enable visual component library for the project]
- Add a `TButton` object
- Check the button's `Action` property in the *Object Inspector* [image: Object inspector displaying 'you cannot set property...' message for a TAction property]

I can deduce that the *"Visual Component Library"* framework is not enabled for the projects displaying `'you cannot set property...'` in the `TAction`' properties dropdown.

---

The problem can be resolved as follows:

- Right click on "Package1.bpl"
  from the Project Manager -> Add New -> VCL Form
- Select Yes [image]
- Save the project (even without saving the new added form)

As result of these actions, in the `Package1.dproj` file, the value of the `Project.PropertyGroup.FrameworkType` node will change from `None` to `VCL` (I don't know if there is an option for this somewhere in the IDE).